# Can a nativescript app be run as a webapp?

Tags: nativescript

I've got a {N} TS app - running fine under Android.

Would it be possible to take that app and run as a webapp - with limitations of course - no access to platform api and hardware etc.

95% of my app is just pages, navigation and http calls.

If the answer is a NO - any suggestions to migrate to make it work under a web browser.

Why? Because at this time I'd prefer to run the app outside the Apple app store.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, well, kinda

Take a look at [this setup](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced) by @NathanWalker

you still have to rewrite the views and change a few things in the providers.

Comment: Just to piggyback and point the obvious out, you have to rewrite the views because NativeScript isn't using a webview or the DOM for its UI. With a little work you could write something that converts NativeScript components into a web element.